# SvgIcon is not a valid JSX element type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm getting a really fustrating TypeScript error in an Electron React App, using MUI and MUI Icons, which while not stopping the build. is something I ideally want to resolve; and is also causing "fun" with defining props for icons too.

Side note, in a past project at my old work, we used `IconDefinition` type and not the base MUI icons, but I cannot recall where these came from.

Here's my non-dev packages:

```
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.10",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.10",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "npm-force-resolutions": "^0.0.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-pdf": "^7.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
    "use-file-picker": "^2.1.1"
```

Dev dependencies:

```
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^7.2.0",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "^1.7.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.10.0",
    "electron": "28.2.3",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.3.0",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
```

*Edit 1: Typescript now bumped to 5.3.3*

And here is an example of some of my code, from `app.tsx`.

*Edit 1: I have tried many variations of importing the icon.*

```
import { AppBar, IconButton, Toolbar } from '@mui/material';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
// import { Menu as MenuIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';
// import { default as MenuIcon } from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
...
  return (
    <>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar variant="dense" disableGutters>
          <IconButton onClick={() => setIsSidebarOpen(true)}>
            <MenuIcon sx={{ color: "blue" }} />
          </IconButton>
          ...
```

And finally the error, under `MenuIcon`:

```
JSX element type 'MenuIcon' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)
'MenuIcon' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type 'typeof import("c:/Users/<user>/Documents/Repos/<repo>/node_modules/@mui/material/SvgIcon/SvgIcon")' is not a valid JSX element type.ts(2786)
(alias) const MenuIcon: typeof SvgIcon
import MenuIcon
```

Image of error:
[image: Image of error]

Answer (score 0):

I was prompted elsewhere to try:
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/issues/1741#issuecomment-1093812197

And this prompted me to re-install my node modules, resulting in:
[image: Package.json changes]

So this looks to be solved, perhaps `npm-force-resolutions` was the solution, and I just failed to apply it earlier.